# Question about the equivalence between Kelvin-Planck and Clausius

Tags: thermodynamics, work, heat-engine

[image]

When we try to prove that if Clausius statement violated then KP is also violated we assume that that cold source gives the same amount of heat as it receives. My question is: How is this proof generally true, doesn't this work only in this specific case? What if the cold source receives more heat than it gives, would that change anything?
I assume this is a proof by contradiction, does choosing the net heat of T1 to be zero generally prove this, or in only this specific case?

Comment: What do you learn by doing energy balances around the various components and the entire system? What changes when $q_1 = q_3$ versus when $q_1 > q_3$ or $q_1 < q_3$?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Well, when we choose $Q1=Q3$ we can say that T1 reservoir doesn't exchange heat so the system violates kelvin-plank, but when it's not equal we can't say that, so it would suggest that it doesn't violet KP.